# generating shifted t distributed numbers and the non centrality parameter?

Tags: r, simulation

[image]when i use `a<-rt(10,3)`and `b <-rnorm(10,3`)+5 trying to get shifted to the right numbers in order to calculate power of the two sample t-test. I get wrong results. There is a lot of literature on the internet talking about the use of the noncentrality parameter to get shifted numbers in order to be able to calculate power. My question how to use noncentrality parameter to get an amount of shifting equal to 5. If I am wrong and that the only method to get shifted numbers from the t distribution is the method introduced at the beginning then please tell me.

```
desired_length<-1000
empty_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = desired_length)
empty_list1 <- vector(mode = "list", length = desired_length)
empty_list2<-vector(mode="list",length=desired_length)
empty_list3<-vector(mode="list",length=desired_length)
empty_list4<-vector(mode="list",length=desired_length)
for (i in 1:1000) {
  

  h<-rt(10,1)

  g<-rt(10,1)

  g1<- rt(10,1)+0.5

  g2<-rt(10,1)+1

  g3<- rt(10,1)+1.5

  g4<- rt(10,1)+2
  a<-cbind(h,g)
  b<-cbind(h,g1)
  c<-cbind(h,g2)
  d<-cbind(h,g3)
  e<-cbind(h,g4)
  empty_list[[i]]<-a
  empty_list1[[i]]<-b
  empty_list2[[i]]<-c
  empty_list3[[i]]<-d
  empty_list4[[i]]<-e
}

pvalue<-numeric(1000)
pvalue1<-numeric(1000)
pvalue2<-numeric(1000)
pvalue3<-numeric(1000)
pvalue4<-numeric(1000)
x<-numeric(5)

for (i in 1:1000){
  pvalue[i]<-t.test(empty_list[[i]][,1],empty_list[[i]][,2])$p.value
  
  pvalue1[i]<-t.test(empty_list1[[i]][,1],empty_list1[[i]][,2])$p.value
  
  pvalue2[i]<-t.test(empty_list2[[i]][,1],empty_list2[[i]][,2])$p.value
  
  pvalue3[i]<-t.test(empty_list3[[i]][,1],empty_list3[[i]][,2])$p.value
  
  pvalue4[i]<-t.test(empty_list4[[i]][,1],empty_list4[[i]][,2])$p.value
  
}
x[1]<-sum(pvalue<0.05)/1000
x[2]<-sum(pvalue1<0.05)/1000
x[3]<-sum(pvalue2<0.05)/1000
x[4]<-sum(pvalue3<0.05)/1000
x[5]<-sum(pvalue4<0.05)/1000
location<-seq(0,2,by =0.5)
plot(location,x,ylab="Power for t1 distributions",xlab="location difference",type = "l",ylim=c(0,1))





combined_data<-matrix(data=NA,nrow = 20,ncol=1000,byrow = F)
for ( i in 1:1000){
  
  combined_data[,i]<-c(empty_list[[i]][,1],empty_list[[i]][,2])
}

combined_data1<-matrix(data=NA,nrow = 20,ncol=1000,byrow = F)
for ( i in 1:1000){
  
  combined_data1[,i]<-c(empty_list1[[i]][,1],empty_list1[[i]][,2])
}

combined_data2<-matrix(data=NA,nrow = 20,ncol=1000,byrow = F)
for ( i in 1:1000){
  
  combined_data2[,i]<-c(empty_list2[[i]][,1],empty_list2[[i]][,2])
}

combined_data3<-matrix(data=NA,nrow = 20,ncol=1000,byrow = F)
for ( i in 1:1000){
  
  combined_data3[,i]<-c(empty_list3[[i]][,1],empty_list3[[i]][,2])
}

combined_data4<-matrix(data=NA,nrow = 20,ncol=1000,byrow = F)
for ( i in 1:1000){
  
  combined_data4[,i]<-c(empty_list4[[i]][,1],empty_list4[[i]][,2])
}

Pvalue_approximator<-function(m){
  
  g1<-m[1:10]
  g2<-m[11:20]
  Tstatistic<- mean(g2)-mean(g1)
  nreps=10000
  G3 <- numeric(nreps)
  for (i in 1:nreps) {
    shuffled_data<-sample(c(m))
    G1 <- (shuffled_data)[1:10] 
    G2 <- (shuffled_data)[11:20]
    G3[i]<-mean(G2)-mean(G1)
  }
  
  m<-(sum(abs(G3) >= abs(Tstatistic))+1)/(nreps+1) 
}
p<-numeric(5)
pval<-apply(combined_data,2,FUN=Pvalue_approximator)
p[1]<-sum( pval < 0.05)/1000 
pval1<-apply(combined_data1,2,FUN=Pvalue_approximator)
p[2]<-sum( pval1 < 0.05)/1000 
pval2<-apply(combined_data2,2,FUN=Pvalue_approximator)
p[3]<-sum( pval2 < 0.05)/1000 
pval3<-apply(combined_data3,2,FUN=Pvalue_approximator)
p[4]<-sum( pval3 < 0.05)/1000 
pval4<-apply(combined_data4,2,FUN=Pvalue_approximator)
p[5]<-sum( pval4 < 0.05)/1000 


lines(location, p, col="red",lty=2)

Diff.med.Pvalue_approximator<-function(m){
  
  g1<-m[1:10]
  g2<-m[11:20]
  a<-abs(c(g1-median(c(g1))))
  b<-abs(c(g2-median(c(g2))))
  ab<-2*median(c(a,b))
  ac<-abs(median(c(g2))-median(c(g1)))
  Tstatistic =ac/ab
  
  nreps=10000
  G3 <- numeric(nreps)
  for (i in 1:nreps) {
    shuffled_data<-sample(c(m))
    G1 <- (shuffled_data)[1:10] 
    G2 <- (shuffled_data)[11:20]
    o<-abs(c(G1-median(c(G1))))
    v<-abs(c(G2-median(c(G2))))
    ov<-2*median(c(o,v))
    oc<-abs(median(c(G2))-median(c(G1)))
    G3[i]<- oc/ov
  }
  m<-(sum(G3 >= Tstatistic)+1)/(nreps+1)
  
}
po<-numeric(5)
pval<-apply(combined_data,2,FUN=Diff.med.Pvalue_approximator)
po[1]<-sum( pval < 0.05)/1000 
pval1<-apply(combined_data1,2,FUN=Diff.med.Pvalue_approximator)
po[2]<-sum( pval1 < 0.05)/1000 
pval2<-apply(combined_data2,2,FUN=Diff.med.Pvalue_approximator)
po[3]<-sum( pval2 < 0.05)/1000 
pval3<-apply(combined_data3,2,FUN=Diff.med.Pvalue_approximator)
po[4]<-sum( pval3 < 0.05)/1000 
pval4<-apply(combined_data4,2,FUN=Diff.med.Pvalue_approximator)
po[5]<-sum(pval4 < 0.05)/1000 

lines(location, po, col="green",lty=1)






wilcoxon.Pvalue_approximator<-function(m){
  
  g1<-m[1:10]
  g2<-m[11:20]
  l = length(g1)
  rx = rank(c(g1,g2))
  rf<-rx[11:20]
  Tstatistic<-sum(rf)
  nreps=10000
  G3 <- numeric(nreps)
  for (i in 1:nreps) {
    shuffled_data<-sample(c(m))
    G1 <- (shuffled_data)[1:10] 
    G2 <- (shuffled_data)[11:20]
    rt<-rank(c(G1,G2))
    ra<-rt[11:20]
    G3[i]<-sum(ra)
  }
  
  m<-2*(sum(abs(G3) >= abs(Tstatistic))+1)/(nreps+1)
}


pw<-numeric(5)
pval<-apply(combined_data,2,FUN=wilcoxon.Pvalue_approximator)
pw[1]<-sum( pval < 0.05)/1000 
pval1<-apply(combined_data1,2,FUN=wilcoxon.Pvalue_approximator)
pw[2]<-sum( pval1 < 0.05)/1000 
pval2<-apply(combined_data2,2,FUN=wilcoxon.Pvalue_approximator)
pw[3]<-sum( pval2 < 0.05)/1000 
pval3<-apply(combined_data3,2,FUN=wilcoxon.Pvalue_approximator)
pw[4]<-sum( pval3 < 0.05)/1000 
pval4<-apply(combined_data4,2,FUN=wilcoxon.Pvalue_approximator)
pw[5]<-sum( pval4 < 0.05)/1000 


lines(location, pw, col="blue",lty=1)

HLE2.Pvalue_approximator<-function(m){
  
  g1<-m[1:10]
  g2<-m[11:20]
  u<-median(c(g1))
  v<-median(c(g2))
  x<-c(g1-u)
  y<-c(g2-v)
  xy<-c(x,y)
  a<-outer(xy,xy,"-")
  t<-a[lower.tri(a)]
  ab<- median(c(abs(t)))
  ac<-abs(median(c(outer(g2,g1,"-"))))
  Tstatistic = ac/ab
  
  nreps=10000
  G3 <- numeric(nreps)
  for (i in 1:nreps) {
    shuffled_data<-sample(c(m))
    G1 <- (shuffled_data)[1:10] 
    G2 <- (shuffled_data)[11:20]
    f<-median(c(G1))
    h<-median(c(G2))
    p<-c(G1-f)
    r<-c(G2-h)
    pr<-c(p,r)
    pu<-outer(pr,pr,"-")
    xc<-pu[lower.tri(pu)]
    b<- median(c(abs(xc)))
    acn<-abs(median(c(outer(G2,G1,"-"))))
    G3[i]<- acn/b
  }
  m<-(sum(G3 >= Tstatistic)+1)/(nreps+1)
  
}

phl<-numeric(5)
pval<-apply(combined_data,2,FUN=HLE2.Pvalue_approximator)
phl[1]<-sum( pval < 0.05)/1000 
pval1<-apply(combined_data1,2,FUN=HLE2.Pvalue_approximator)
phl[2]<-sum( pval1 < 0.05)/1000 
pval2<-apply(combined_data2,2,FUN=HLE2.Pvalue_approximator)
phl[3]<-sum( pval2 < 0.05)/1000 
pval3<-apply(combined_data3,2,FUN=HLE2.Pvalue_approximator)
phl[4]<-sum( pval3 < 0.05)/1000 
pval4<-apply(combined_data4,2,FUN=HLE2.Pvalue_approximator)
phl[5]<-sum( pval4 < 0.05)/1000 


lines(location, phl, col="orange",lty=1)


HLE1.Pvalue_approximator<-function(m){
  
  g1<-m[1:10]
  g2<-m[11:20]
  u<-median(c(g1))
  v<-median(c(g2))
  x<-c(g1-u)
  y<-c(g2-v)
  xy<-c(x,y)
  a<-outer(xy,xy,"-")
  t<-a[lower.tri(a)]
  ab<- median(c(abs(t)))
  ma<-outer(g2,g2,"+")
  deno1<-median(c(ma[lower.tri(ma)]/2))
  mn<-outer(g1,g1,"+")
  deno2<-median(c(mn[lower.tri(mn)]/2))
  ac<-abs(deno1-deno2)
  Tstatistic =ac/ab
  
  nreps=10000
  G3 <- numeric(nreps)
  for (i in 1:nreps) {
    shuffled_data<-sample(c(m))
    G1 <- (shuffled_data)[1:10] 
    G2 <- (shuffled_data)[11:20]
    f<-median(c(G1))
    h<-median(c(G2))
    p<-c(G1-f)
    r<-c(G2-h)
    pr<-c(p,r)
    pu<-outer(pr,pr,"-")
    xc<-pu[lower.tri(pu)]
    b<- median(c(abs(xc)))
    mas<-outer(G2,G2,"+")
    dn1<-median(c(mas[lower.tri(mas)]/2))
    mns<-outer(G1,G1,"+")
    dn2<-median(c(mns[lower.tri(mns)]/2))
    an<-abs(dn2-dn1)
    G3[i]<- an/b
  }
  m<-(sum(G3 >= Tstatistic)+1)/(nreps+1)
  
}
pl<-numeric(5)
pval<-apply(combined_data,2,FUN=HLE1.Pvalue_approximator)
pl[1]<-sum( pval < 0.05)/1000 
pval1<-apply(combined_data1,2,FUN=HLE1.Pvalue_approximator)
pl[2]<-sum( pval1 < 0.05)/1000 
pval2<-apply(combined_data2,2,FUN=HLE1.Pvalue_approximator)
pl[3]<-sum( pval2 < 0.05)/1000 
pval3<-apply(combined_data3,2,FUN=wilcoxon.Pvalue_approximator)
pl[4]<-sum( pval3 < 0.05)/1000 
pval4<-apply(combined_data4,2,FUN=wilcoxon.Pvalue_approximator)
pl[5]<-sum( pval4 < 0.05)/1000 

lines(location, pl, col="brown",lty=1)



median_Pvalue_approximator<-function(m){
  g1<-m[1:10]
  g2<-m[11:20]
  rt<-rank(c(g1,g2))
  rt<-rt[11:20]
  Tstatistic<-sum(rt > 10.5)
  nreps=10000
  G3 <- numeric(nreps)
  for (i in 1:nreps) {
    shuffled_data<-sample(c(m))
    G1 <- (shuffled_data)[1:10] 
    G2 <- (shuffled_data)[11:20]
    ra<-rank(c(G1,G2))
    ra<-ra[11:20]
    G3[i]<-sum(ra > 10.5)
    
  }
  m<-(sum(G3 >= Tstatistic)+1)/(nreps+1)
}

pm<-numeric(5)
pval<-apply(combined_data,2,FUN=median_Pvalue_approximator)
pm[1]<-sum( pval < 0.05)/1000 
pval1<-apply(combined_data1,2,FUN=median_Pvalue_approximator)
pm[2]<-sum( pval1 < 0.05)/1000 
pval2<-apply(combined_data2,2,FUN=median_Pvalue_approximator)
pm[3]<-sum( pval2 < 0.05)/1000 
pval3<-apply(combined_data3,2,FUN=median_Pvalue_approximator)
pm[4]<-sum( pval3 < 0.05)/1000 
pval4<-apply(combined_data4,2,FUN=median_Pvalue_approximator)
pm[5]<-sum( pval4 < 0.05)/1000 


lines(location, pm, col="yellow",lty=1)
legend("topleft", legend=c("t.test","HLE2", "HLE","Diff.med","median","wilcoxon","mean diff"),col=c( "black","orange","brown","green","yellow","blue","red"), lty=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2), cex=0.8, text.font=4, bg='white')
```

Comment: Are you sure you need noncentrality parameter (NCP) for the shift? NCP is a lot more than just a shift. Why `rt(10,3)+5` is not working for you? Pure shift should be `rt(10,3)+5`, not `rt(10,3,ncp=5)`

Answer (score 3):

Ok, we have t-Distribution which could be written as

T(n) = N(0,1)*√[n/χ<sup>2</sup>(n)]

where N(0,1) is standard normal, and χ<sup>2</sup>(n) is [Chi-squared distribtion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution). This is pretty standard stuff.

If we want shifted distribution, we add shift `μ`, so

T(n)+μ = N(0,1)*√[n/χ<sup>2</sup>(n)] + μ (1)

If we want non-central parameter (NCP) equal to μ, and [Non-central t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution) we shift GAUSSIAN in the expression above

T(n, NCP=μ) = N(μ,1)*√[n/χ<sup>2</sup>(n)]=(N(0,1)+μ)*√[n/χ<sup>2</sup>(n)]=

=N(0,1)*√[n/χ<sup>2</sup>(n)] + μ*√[n/χ<sup>2</sup>(n)] (2)

Do you see the difference? In the eq(1) we add constant. In the eq(2 ) we add constant multiplied by some ugly looking random variable. Those distributions are different and will produce different results. Use with care.

Standard `T(n)` would be symmetric wrt 0, and `T(n)+μ` would be symmetric wrt `μ`, but non-central T would have asymmetry, you're mixing symmetric T(n) with asymmetric term μ*√[n/χ<sup>2</sup>(n)]. You could at graphs in Wikipedia for non-central `T(n)`

UPDATE

running your code (yes, took quite some time, probably more than 12 hours), I've got

[image]

UPDATE II

I'm a bit more familiar with Python nowadays, so I recoded part of the test in Python and ran it, it is pretty much instant, and for t-distribution with df=3 I got a lot more close to the paper graph, values up to 0.8. You could also quickly make graph for df=1, and again should get close to the paper result. Or you could replace `rng.standard_t` with `rng.normal(size=N)` and you will get graph with close to 1 power at large shifts.

Code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = np.random.default_rng(312345)

N = 10 # Sample Size

α = 0.05

shift = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
power = np.zeros(len(shift))

for k in range(0, len(shift)):
    s = shift[k] # current shift
    c = 0        # counter how many times we reject
    for _ in range(0, 1000):

        a = rng.standard_t(df=3, size=N) # baseline sample
        b = rng.standard_t(df=3, size=N) + s # sample with shift

        t, p = stats.ttest_ind(a, b, equal_var=True) # t-Test from two independent samples, assuming equal variance
        if p <= α:
            c += 1

    power[k] = float(c)/1000.0

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)

ax.plot(shift, power, 'r-')

plt.show()
```

and graph

[image]

UPDATE III

And here is R code which is pretty much like Python one and makes about the same graph

```
N <- 10

shift <- c(0., 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0)
power <- c(0., 0., 0., 0., 0.)

av <- 0.05

samples <- function(n) {
    rchisq(n, df=3) #rnorm(n) #rt(n, df=3) #rt(n, df=1)
}

pvalue <- function(a, b) {
    t.test(a, b, var.equal = TRUE)$p.value
}

for (k in 1:5) {
    s <- shift[k]

    p <- replicate(1000, pvalue(samples(N), samples(N) + s))
    cc <- sum(p <= av)

    power[k] <- cc/1000.0
}

plot(shift, power, type="l")
```

UPDATE IV

No, I was unable to get their (in paper) t-test graph in Fig.1, bottom right for χ<sup>2</sup>(3), in both R and Python. What I'm getting is something like graph below.

[image]

Comment: you still not understand me .In fact i used the shift method suggested by me and by you ,But when i did not get the same curves as plotted in Figure 1 in  this article https://eldorado.tu-dortmund.de/bitstream/2003/27803/1/DP_1911_SFB823_Fried_Dehling.pdf . I said perhaps we do not shift t distribution like that so i googled and i find some litterarture talking about ncp so i become confused .

Comment: In fig 1 center left and bottom left you can find plots please compare then with the code that i will add right now .Please do not run the Diff ,HLE and HLE2 because they take a lot of time but only t test ,wilcoxon, P-approximator and the median test (the last lone)

Comment: already added .Please compare them withntheir homologues ragarding the look and how they are ranked

Comment: if you are asking why these 100000 samples inside the tests .These are permutation version of the tests (median,wilcoxn,...) since the sample size is very tiny

Comment: ok when you are done with running Please give me an answer.HLE2 ,HLE and Diff take hours and hours of time do not run them.Look just to the others and you will find that there bif differnce between the plots

Comment: do you an new feedback?

Comment: @ZB I've looked quickly at the code, so far no insight. I'll continue to look...

Comment: do you mean just looking with your eyes or running it with R?

Comment: @ZB I ran it, and got picture in the updated answer. This is what are you getting as well? And you expected to get Figure 1 fom paper?

Comment: i mean the plot in the bottom left of Fig1

Comment: Thank you very much .How did you getb that? when i run the code Igave you i different plot.I mean the ranking of curves ( which one is over the other one) is not like ih bottom left of Fig1,How did you do that?

Comment: if you take a look in the plot in bottom left of Fig 1 you remarque that many curves take valus larger than those taken by your curves .For example the green curve take values greater than 0.8 .can you explain why? i got the same thing.is it possible that the  authors of this article have commited mistakes

Comment: if we change 1 by 3 .I mean we use 3 degrees of freedom.will we get plot like in center left of Fig1?

Comment: @i  began today to repreduce the plot you obtainned but it seems tha green curve has not the same form as yours.Look at my plot please!!.what is wrong ?  does the used computer play a role? or just because you have changed something

Comment: @ZB well, I just ran it. Windows 10 x64, R 4.0.2 x64

Comment: how do you find your results compared to the plot of Fig1 (bottom left)

Comment: @ZB please check update, I don't think computer plays a role, because I repeated code myself, and got close to the paper answer

Comment: @ZB And here is another update with R code. Looks pretty much the same as Python, you could play with df  or replace t-sampling with normal samples

Comment: Thank you very much.But i am still insisting that there something to do with noncentrality parameter when calculating power curves of t distribution or chi distribution so one last request please replace rt by rchisq and dgrees pf freedom 1 by 3 and just look at the first curve and you find out the catastrophe compared to the bottom right of Fig1.Pleeeeeeeassse Try it

Comment: @ZB No, I was unable to get t-test to work like their graph in Fig.1 in bottom left for chi2(df=3) distribution. I've updated R code so you could easily replace any sampling method you want as well as any test you want, test should return p-value, sampling should return array of RVs. And it is pretty much instant. With this code you could test any distribution, any shift and any test with easy. If you happy with the answer, please accept it and/or bump it as well

Comment: Thank you again.I have consulted some professors in R blogs and they mean there is only one way to calculate power of t distribution and that is by non centraliyt parameter ncp.I advise to learn about it

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `ncp` (**N**on **C**entrality **P**arameter) argument of `rt()`

```
rt(10, 3, ncp = 4)
```

Have a look at the helpfile to see how you need to set the ncp argument.

Comment: do you mean when i use ncp=4 i will get a shift of 5?

Comment: if i want to shift with an amount of a ( a is a real numer ) how to do to the right ncp?

Comment: @ZB no, NCP is never about pure shift, you cannot use it for a shift. rt(10,3)+shift should do the trick

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux but when I use it to get power curves i get curves not as the ones of the article i am studying

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux can i give the link of article and my code so you understand why i am confused

Comment: @ZB take a look at the answer, see how it fits your problem